# Searching gmail using android api

Tags: android, gmail-imap

I want to search inside gmail label based on emailid. I have found a example https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/ it fetches all the labels with count. I want to search email based on email id. Is it even possible to do it based on some contentprovider?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Searching after a long time i found out that you need to give permission to your app in https://console.developers.google.com.

Then follow steps mentioned in the link

http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html.